# Alternative to eval() when reading a cookie value

Tags: javascript, cookies, eval

I've storing a property in a cookie for user preferences, to fetch the cookie I use the following code:

```
function getCookie(cookieName) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie) {
        var arr = document.cookie.split((escape(cookieName) + '='));
        if (2 <= arr.length) {
            var arr2 = arr[1].split(';');
            cookieValue = unescape(arr2[0]);
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Used: `var userPref = getCookie("userPref");`

Then I'm using the value stored in the cookie like so, for instance:

```
$('body').css('background-color', eval(userPref));
```

Is it possible to convert the `userPref` property without using `eval()` function?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? What is the value of `userPref`, and what effect does running `eval()` on it have?

Comment: I need to use it as a string.

Comment: I don't understand; surely it already is a string?

Comment: If it is, I don't seem to be able to use it as a string I have to wrap it in eval()

Comment: Did you tried `new String (userPref)` ?

Comment: What error are you actually seeing, and why do you think it has something to do with the variable not being a string? Try running `console.log(userPref)`, and see what output you get in your browser's Developer Tools (usually under F12).

Comment: I get the value in need output to the console, perhaps its a function?

Comment: @CLiown Please show us the value you get. Please also tell us what error you are seeing if you pass this value to the `css()` function. Without this information, we cannot help you, because we don't know what effect `eval()` is currently having, and why it seems to be necessary for your code to work.